# Use Mathematica to calculate matrix range?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Mathematica has RowReduce[], how can I use this to calculate a basis for the  range of any matrix?

Given

```
A={{1,1,1,1,2},{1,2,4,0,5},{2,1,-1,4,0},{-1,1,5,-1,2}};

RowReduce[A]=={{1,0,-2,0,1},{0,1,3,0,2},{0,0,0,1,-1},{0,0,0,0,0}}
```

The leading 1's in the reduced row echelon form select the first, second, and fourth column vectors of A as a basis for the range of A. How do I program mathematica to make that selection after calculating RowReduce[A]?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no such thing as *the* basis. Secondly, the range of a transformation is generated by the columns, so `RowReduce[Transpose[M]]` ought to do it.

Comment: This is not what I had in mind at all.

Comment: @PhillipDukes Do you always speak in riddles?

Comment: "This is not what I had in mind at all." - then @Phillip, can you come up with a formulation that won't confuse answerers?

Comment: @J.M. thank you, I hope my example is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Long form:

```
A = (* your matrix *)
reduced = RowReduce[A];
positions = DeleteMissing[FirstPosition[1] /@ reduced];
A[[Catenate[positions]]]
```

In one line:

```
basis[A_] := 
 A[[Catenate[DeleteMissing[FirstPosition[1] /@ RowReduce[A]]]]]
```